# how do I tell cgo not to compile a file?

Tags: go, cgo

for a regular go file I say

```
// +build !windows
```

however cgo interprets this as c code to get compiled

So what do I have to do?

Comment: Do you want to disable cgo, or just ignore a file?

Comment: From what I understand, files designated as being C code are compiled using either gc by default or gcc (by flag to cgo) so I think your best bet is to figure out how to tell gc to ignore a file and then apply that here.

Comment: i dont want it processed at all (go or gcc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The build constraint must appear before your package declaration.

**Incorrect**

```
package mypackage

// +build !windows

// #include <header.h>
//
// ...
import "C"
```

**Correct**

```
// +build !windows

package mypackage

// #include <header.h>
//
// ...
import "C"
```

Comment: As an aside - I cant get over how sensitive cgo is to blank lines. Miss the line between the +build line and package - the build line is ignored. Add a line between a #cgo line and "C" includes and it (the #cgo) is ignored - NOT OBVIOUS

Comment: @pm100 actually, it stats so in the documentation: [To distinguish build constraints from package documentation, a series of build constraints must be followed by a blank line.](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/)

Comment: @OneOfOne unless they are constraints for cgo flags - in which case they must not have a blank line